# Angular 2 child route component loading problem

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to learn angular routing. There are two selectboxes. When a select option is selected `lookup` function is called. I can access `ngModel` values. First selectbox option is select `ProvinceComponent` is loading. Here the problem is second selecbox is selected `DistrictComponent` doesnt load. Here stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-awpj1d

```
<select [(ngModel)]="province" (ngModelChange)="lookup($event, 1);">
    <option *ngFor="let i of provinces" [value]="i.i">{{i.n}}</option>
</select>
<select [(ngModel)]="district" (ngModelChange)="lookup($event, 2);">
    <option *ngFor="let i of d" [value]="i.i">{{i.n}}</option>
</select>
```

Here `appRoutes` options

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/analyse", pathMatch: "full" },
   {
     path: "analyse",
     component: AnalyseComponent,
     children: [
       {path: ":province", component: ProvinceComponent,children: [
          { path: ":district", component: DistrictComponent }]
       }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this piece of code

```
component: ProvinceComponent,children: [
    { path: ":district", component: DistrictComponent }]
}
```

says that DistrictComponent will be rendered inside of Province component in place of `<router-outlet>`. and it seems your `ProvinceComponent` doesn't have outlet in it. just add the element where you want to render child route inside of a parent

Comment: it must be [{path: ':province', component: ProvinceComponent},
            {path: ':province/:district', component: DistrictComponent}] thanks a lot of